# Ruby on Rails populate 1 field from belongs to table id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am new to ruby on rails.  I have created two models brand and product.  A brand can be related to many products.  I used the scaffolding because that is what our lecturer expects us to do in our project.

I have tried to setup my product screen so that when you enter a product you get a dropdown list of brand names to choose from.   When you enter the product details, select the brand name, and click submit; the brand_id from the selected band name is saved into the product.brand_id table.  (I believe brand_id is automatically created in the products table when I setup has_many in the controller).

I have tried doing this with a collection_set but I'm struggling badly.  I have tried using some of the tips on stack overflow but none of them worked and as a last resort I have tried placing a post myself.

In the models I added the following:

```
class Brand < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :product
    validates :brand_name, presence: true
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :brand
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

From what I was given to understand, this means that product table will have brand_id as well as id.

In the products controller I added the following:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @brand   = Brand.all
    @product = Product.new
  end
... more code ...
```

In the form for the product view  I added the following

```
<%= form_for(product) do |f| %>
  <% if product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :model %>
    <%= f.text_field :model %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :vat %>
    <%= f.text_field :vat %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image_uri %>
    <%= f.text_field :image_uri %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <%= f.collection_select :brand_id, @brand, :id, :brand_name %>
  </div>



  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :products
  resources :sales_orders
  resources :payments
  resources :filter_group_items
  resources :filter_groups
  resources :categories
  resources :sales_order_lines
  resources :brands
  resources :addresses
  get '/cart' => 'cart#index'
  get '/products' => 'products#index'
  get '/brands' => 'brands#index'
  get '/users' => 'users#index'
  get '/addresses' => 'addresses#index'
  get '/payments' => 'payments#index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  #root 'application#hello'
    # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  #root 'welcome#index'
  root 'products#index'
end
```

I get the following error
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/ssd_project/app/views/products/_form.html.erb where line #40 raised:

undefined method `brand_id' for #
Did you mean?  brand

```
39 <div class="field">
40   <%= f.collection_select :brand_id, @brand, :id, :brand_name %>
41 </div>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/products/new.html.erb

If anyone has any advice on how to do this I'd be very grateful.

New Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :products
  resources :sales_orders
  resources :payments
  resources :filter_group_items
  resources :filter_groups
  resources :categories
  resources :sales_order_lines
  resources :brands
  resources :addresses

  resources :brands do
      resources :products
  end

  get '/cart' => 'cart#index'
  get '/products' => 'products#new'
  get '/brands' => 'brands#index'
  get '/users' => 'users#index'
  get '/addresses' => 'addresses#index'
  get '/payments' => 'payments#index'



  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  #root 'application#hello'
    # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  #root 'welcome#index'
  root 'products#index'
end
```

Database Schema schema.rb

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160706122948) do

  create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "line1"
    t.string   "line2"
    t.string   "line3"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "post_code"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "brands", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "brand_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "filter_group_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "filter_groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "payments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "date"
    t.decimal  "amount"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "model"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.decimal  "vat"
    t.string   "image_uri"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "sales_order_lines", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "qty"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.decimal  "total"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "sales_orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "date"
    t.decimal  "total"
    t.decimal  "vat"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.boolean  "admin_user", default: false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this:

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.collection_select :brand_id, Brand.all, :id, :brand_name %>
</div>
```

The second argument would be a collection and you can get all the possible Brands with `Brand.all`

Then you can take out the line  `@brand   = Brand.all` in the Products controller under new action

Also, in your form i think you should have form_for(@product) rather than product.  You want the instance variable @product

Are your routes arranged so that Product is nested under Brand?  Would be helpful to see the routes too.  That is another potential problem

**EDITED:**

This would be an example of a nested route (which your app doesn't have):

```
resources :brands do
  resources :products
end
```

This would produce a routes like this:

/brands/:brand_id/products/:id

So I recreated your app and found that the `form_for(product)` was causing an error for me.  If it's switched to `@product`, an instance variable (which you already set in your controller), then your code worked as expected.  `form_for(@product)` should match the `@product = Product.new` in your products controller, new action.  Looking back, my other suggestion about how to do the collection.select was more stylistic in nature but I believe it makes your code easier to follow.

***SECOND EDIT:***

Your schema.rb file shows the problem.  Your Product table doesn't contain a reference to the Brand table even though you've associated the two with `has_many` and `belongs_to` in the models(contrary to what you thought this doesn't happen automatically, but rather through a database migration).  The point is, the product table is missing a `brand_id` column

Firstly, I would unnest your routes so that it was as before:

```
  resources :products
  resources :brands
```

Then you will need to run a migration to add the brand reference to the products table.  In your command line, use the command `rails generate migration add_reference_to_products`, then in your migration folder (which can be found in /db/migrate), open up the migration file you just created. add the following to your `def change` block:

```
def change
  add_reference :products, :brand, index: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

Make sure to save the file.  Then in your command line type `rake db:migrate` to run the migration.  This will create a column for `brand_id` in your products table, and your code should work

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your reply. I have placed the error I got and routes.rb file in the original post above.  I tried doing your suggestion but unfortunately got the same error.  I don't think form_for(@product) is the issue as other forms work with form_for(user) instead of form_for(@user).  I am not sure what you mean by routes arranged so that product is nested under brand.  That could be the issue.  If you could provide some more info.  I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: I did the other changes you suggested.  I suspect my problem is with the way I have setup my tables up.  I think I have not setup routes.rb link correctly.  If I put the following in the code the screen renders correctly.    <%= f.collection_select :id , Brand.all, :id, :brand_name %> I have enclosed a copy of changed routes.rb.  If you see anything obvious let me know.  I'll speak to the lecturer and get more help.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to use the nested routes in your case...actually it will make things more complicated.   Could you post your schema.rb?

Comment: Hi I added the schema above.  I'm not sure if it helps

Comment: actually it helped a lot.  please see latest edit.  hope that solves the issue

Comment: That is what was wrong.  Thank you so, so much for your help.  I really appreciate it.